# Is there a Django database backend test suite?

Tags: django

I'm experimenting with a Django database backend for a [pure-python PostgreSQL client library](https://github.com/d33tah/bpgsql) that I copied from psycopg2. My "hello, world" project seems to work, but I'd like to test how many corner cases aren't covered yet. Is there a test suite I could use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django source tree, there's `tests` directory. Replace contents of `tests/test_sqlite.py` with your backend setup and run `./runtests backends` to see test results.